# export html page as password encrypted pdf using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I want to export my html page as password protected pdf using javascript.

I have a JS code for export html as pdf using kendo pdf,but i want to export html page as encrypted pdf using JS

```
function Exportnote(){ 
     var invno =  "<?php echo $key->invoice_id.'-'.$key->invoice_series; ?>";
kendo.drawing
   .drawDOM("#notefile", 
   { 
       paperSize: "A4",
       margin: { top: "1cm",left: "1cm", right: "1cm"},
       scale: 0.8,
       height: 500
   })
       .then(function(group){
      kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group,  "Notefile_"+invno+'.pdf')
   });
}
```

My question is "I can create a PDF with Kendo, but how do I password protect it?"

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Do you mean: How to create a PDF with Kendo? Or: I can create a PDF with Kendo, but how do you password protect it? Or something else? Please write your question in ... your question

Comment: Hi Yunzen and Green ,my question is "I can create a PDF with Kendo, but how do I password protect it?"

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a password on a PDF using the Kendo PDF Export

Comment: Thank you for your information,other than kendo is any method available to set password on pdf export?

Comment: Nothing springs to mind when using a pure JS solution. If you wanted to add password protection etc you should probably look at doing this server side instead of on the client.